# Syncing MAMP MySQL Database on MEGA

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, localhost, mamp

SO I've read countless tutorials and I've spent hours trying to solve this but have run out of ideas.  Trying to sync my Wordpress database on MEGA (every other tutorial said dropbox but I got MEGA) and everything but one things works on my windows PC.

I've installed MAMP for both (available for Mac and windows now), made them the same settings and properly integrated MEGASync with it.  I created the symlink from both Windows and Mac and updates seem to be happening when I make changes or fool around with wp-config to fix this.

With wordpress I ran the installer on the MAC and it works fine for syncing.  On Windows 8.1 however everything functions between MEGA but when connecting to http://localhost:8888 or http://127.0.0.1:8888 Im simply getting a 'Waiting for Connection". Opening phpmyadmin from either computer shows the database I created as well.

Things I've tried.
- Turn off firewall
- Ran a netstat -a command and found it was listening on 0.0.0.0:8888
- Tried to visit localhost:8889 (mysql) and it downloaded a file.
- Made sure my hosts file had 127.0.0.1 localhost and has ::1 localhost
- Can ping localhost and 127.0.0.1
- Checked apache logs and found them empty

Anything I can do to try and log where to narrow down why it's timing out (it seems) on my local windows box?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's much of a solution but did solve this.  I uninstalled both MAMP servers (Mac and Windows) and did the entire setup process but started on the Windows machine first this time.

I think the problem was a different structure had been synced (not synced) from both computers (Mac was looking like a different file structure).

No I see the proper contents in both directories.